# How to read .dat file float value as float instead of object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am reading a data file using `read_csv`. I have a float column, which has value as blank, 0, 1, 1.3, 5.4 etc. When I check my data frame, this column type as "object" instead of float. Below is the syntax I used:

```
Source=pd.read_csv(dat.gz", sep='\Ç',keep_default_na=False,header=None,engine='python')
```

Is there anyway to have this column as float when reading itself?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem lies in the blank cells. Pandas probably can't proces this as a float, so it sets the whole column as 'object'.

You can either set the column to numeric within the pd.read_csv function:

```
Source = pd.read_csv("dat.gz", sep='\Ç', , dtype={"yourColumn" : np.float64}, keep_default_na=False, header=None,engine='python')
```

Or you can correct it afterwards. It should probably look something like this:

```
 Source['yourColumn'] = pd.to_numeric(Source['yourColumn'], errors='coerce')
```

The 'coerce' part makes sure that every cell that can't be converted to a numeric value will be changed to NaN.

Comment: Thank you. it helped me some extent. But my input file is very dynamic, it would be difficult to give column names every time. is there any other way to solve this probelm

Comment: What do you mean with it being "very dynamic". Do the column names change (or don't have a name), does the number of columns change, of does the column (or columns) that should have floats changes places? Maybe if I have more insight in what it looks like, I can be of more help in finding a working solution.

Comment: I have more than 150 input files, each file has different number of columns, So i want dynamically read the file with out specifying the datatypes at column level.

Comment: And if you just use ' keep_default_na=True' (or just skip it, because True is the default behavior)?